# How to find fast modular exponentiation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I need to find $$5448^{5^3} \pmod{11251}$$ and $$6909^{5^3} \pmod{11251}$$ fast? I couldn't calculate it with normal tricks.

Comment: Note: $11251$ is prime.

Comment: Note: $11250$ is divisible by $5^3$.

Comment: It is not too difficult to find $5448^5 \pmod{11251}$, then do that again, and again

Comment: $n^{5^4}\equiv 1 \pmod{11251}$

Comment: Just about the *fastest* way I know to calculate $5448^{5^3} \pmod{11251}$ is to type `pow(5448, 5**3, 11251)` into the [Python](https://www.python.org/) shell. But I assume you're after something else?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm assuming he wants a fast way to do it by hand. I'm working on it right now, but I've hit a block. If we take both expressions to the $90^\text{th}$ power then we can use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), to find that both of the expressions are solutions $x$ to $$x^{90}\equiv 1 \pmod{11251}$$

I'm not sure how to find the relevant [roots of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity_modulo_n).

Comment: @ugradmath It seems that you got this question from [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=cbl_BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=primitive+root+of+11251&source=bl&ots=qEaEl8x5F4&sig=Ky3RUIMtAznwDxQ5CJMR1nuLBWk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WACUVNeVEYO1ggS7oYKQBQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=primitive%20root%20of%2011251&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $11251$ is prime and equal to $5^3 \cdot  90 + 1$.

$$\left(5448^{5^3}\right)^{90} \equiv 5448^{11250} \pmod{11251}$$

$$\left(6909^{5^3}\right)^{90} \equiv 6909^{11250} \pmod{11251}$$

By [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),

$$\left(6909^{5^3}\right)^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{11251}$$

$$\left(5448^{5^3}\right)^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{11251}$$

Now we have that your two expressions are solutions $x$ to the equation

$$x^{90} \equiv 1 \pmod{11251}$$

See [this answer by André Nicolas on another Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158356/111946) for how to finish the beast. Reducing the problem to an equation to the above form probably isn't the best way to do it, but it should work.